# DateEntry class in tkcalendar bug in runtime

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

During runtime, the DateEntry class exhibits some odd behavior. When clicking the dropdown, I'm presented with the following bug - calendar details not displaying. If I double click the dropdown, the bug resolves, but the formatting is very strange and hard for a user to read (white text on white background). Am I doing something wrong here? If not, does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

[image]

[image]

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Billables Entry Form")

frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack(padx=20, pady=10)


date_label = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Date")
date_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

date_entry = DateEntry(frame, selectmode='day', year=currentYear, month=currentMonth, day=1)

date_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue on macOS; see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/41). You can try adding this line before your `mainloop` but that appears to only work on old versions.

```py
date_entry._top_cal.overrideredirect(False)
```

If you have a GitHub account, you can comment on the issue to raise its importance.