# Is it possible to get a dropdown list of date just by a single click in tkcalendar of tkinter python?

Tags: python, date, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkcalendar

I'm working on a date entry using DateEntry in tkcalendar of tkinter python with the code below. While running I have to double-click the down arrow button beside the DateEntry space to get a drop-down date list, is it possible to get the list just by a single click on the arrow button? I've searched a lot across the web and got no results so far. Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("514x384+0+0")

def show_date():
    data = aDate.get()
    var.set(str(data))

var = tk.StringVar()
label1 = ttk.Label(window, text="Please pick a Date:")
label2 = ttk.Label(window,textvariable=var)
aButton = ttk.Button(window,text = 'submit',command=show_date)
aDate = DateEntry(window,selectmode='day')
label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
label2.grid(row=1,column=0)
aDate.grid(row=2,column=0)
aButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

After reading the other question [DateEntry class in tkcalendar bug in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76751462/dateentry-class-in-tkcalendar-bug-in-runtime), I think my question is probably related with my macOS version which is Monterey version 12.6.8, any comments or suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Comment: It worked for me with as single click.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateEntry class in tkcalendar bug in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76751462/dateentry-class-in-tkcalendar-bug-in-runtime)

Comment: @toyotaSupra, thanks for your comment. I'm thinking maybe my question is related with my macOS version which is Monterey version 12.6.8.

Comment: @drchicken, thanks for giving the link. I'm using macOS so the question is simiar with mine, but that solution doesn't works for me, probably because my macOS version is newer? My macOS is Monterey version 12.6.8, any further suggestion is welcome!

Comment: I was going to ask  you about macos. Here is link https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/

Comment: @toyotaSupra Thank you for providing the link. There are many exciting widgets I may use later in my program, but there's no DateEntry widget yet,  let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @suniu If you click through to the GitHub issue there's users with the same bug on macOS Monterey, Big Sur, Catalina, and Ventura so I think it's a macOS issue and not specific to your version. :(

Comment: @drchicken I agree it's a macOS issue, it seems there's no solution yet.